# Set maximum cmdheight

Tags: command-line

Is there a way to limit the command area in vim?

When typing a long command, cmdheight is "temporarily increased", but I like to limit it to one line. What I currently have is illustrated on the left, but I like the behavior on the right:

[image] ----> [image]

Comment: I haven't checked the source to verify, but I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Weird... after reader `:h 'cmdwinheight'` I thought it would do the trick, but it doesn't.

Comment: @lsrdg, `:h cmdwinheight` sets up the command-line window, not the command-line. The former is the one you get by typing `q:` in normal-mode or typing `Ctrl-F` in command-line-mode.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense @klaus. Back to the docs, `:h 'cmdheight'` defaults to 1 and can be used to set a minimal height, but not the maximum... still curious.